# How reliable is HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: http-referer

I need to check and record the referrer of visitors to my web application. How reliable is using `HTTP_REFERER`? And are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using `HTTP_REFERER` isn't reliable, its value is dependent on the HTTP `Referer` header sent by the browser or client application to the server and therefore can't be trusted because it can be manipulated.

Regarding the `Referer` header, section [15.1.2 of RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.1.2) states:

> Therefore, applications SHOULD supply
> as much control over this information
> as possible to the provider of that
> information.

and

> We suggest, though do not require,
> that a convenient toggle interface be
> provided for the user to enable or
> disable the sending of From and
> Referer information.

Many online privacy tools mangle this value and many browsers such as FireFox have for a long time permitted users to prevent this header being sent. So in a nutshell, I wouldn't rely on it for any serious purpose. For example, securing forms so that drive-by spammers can't post values, because the `Referer` can be spoofed.

For further reading see:

> [Using referer field for authentication or authorization](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309210429/https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_referer_field_for_authentication_or_authorization) (WayBackMachine)

Comment: Agree referer is not reliable and it's not secure, but trust me it does its job pretty well in reducing spam.

Comment: The last link is dead.

Comment: @danrah - fixed. But if you find dead links, then have a look and see if they're on WayBackMachine (http://archive.org) and then just update the post with the most recent available archive copy of the page.