# document.referrer - limitations?

Tags: php, javascript

I am unable to get a lot of referral URLS using document.referrer. I'm not sure what is going on. I would appreciate it if anyone had any info on its limitations (like which browser does not support what) etc.

Is there something else i could use (in a different language perhaps) that covers more browsers etc?

Comment: As I remember some browsers do not send referrer information of https sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure you're on the same page, you do know that if someone types a URL directly in their web browser, the document.referrer property is empty, right?  That being said, you might be interested in a [JavScript method to get all HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript).  If you prefer PHP (since you're using that tag), the [standard $_SERVER variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) will provide what information is available.  Note that the information is only as reliable as the reporting web browser and server, as noted by [Kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put any faith in `document.referrer` in your Javascript code. The value is sent in client side request headers (`Referer`) and as such it can be spoofed and manipulated.

For more info see my answer to this question about the server side `HTTP_REFERER` server variable:

> [How reliable is HTTP_REFERER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer/6023980#6023980)

Answer (score 1):

Which browser are you looking in? If the referring website is sending the traffic via `window.open('some link')` instead of a regular `<a>` tag, then IE will not see a referrer. It thinks it's a new request at that point, similar to you simply going to a URL directly (in which case there is no referrer). Firefox and Chrome do not have the same issue.

This is NOT just a javascript limitation, `HTTP_REFERRER` will NOT  work either in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.referrer` will be an empty string if:

- You access the site directly, by entering the URL;
- You access the site by clicking on a bookmark;
- The source link contains `rel="noreferrer"`;
- The source is a local file;

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer