# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is not working in Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how reliable is HTTP_REFERER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer)

I am using `HTTP_REFERER` in my code, but in Google Chrome, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` contains no value. In Firefox, it's working.

Comment: Http_referer isn't consistant. Php manuel also says it. 1 way could be, catch the current url on client side, send it as parameter to next page on the server side.

Comment: how are you testing?  I didn't notice any difference between chrome and firefox.  referrer registers if user click on a link that lead to your page on which you fetch http_referer . if browser sends it of course. you might have a plugin or setting that suppress that .

Comment: Check your extensions as it's probably a setting in there. BUT, as pointed out by itachi, don't rely on it for anything public. Several "Web Security software" products will block or mask referrer by default and other extensions/plugins will do the same. So if a public facing website, then you don;t know what you're going to get.

Comment: I **post** the data after the i am testing it by `print_r($_SERVER)` i am getting the value of 'HTTP_REFERER' in FF but not in google crome