# Opencart Login to Previous Viewed Page After Logging in?

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, opencart

Opencart Login to Previous Viewed Page After Logging in?

Anyone know a way this can be done? Working on Version 1.5.4

Hope someone can advise/help!

Thanks!

Comment: Do You have a login form in header/column always present (at any page)? If so, is it an extension or You did this for Yourself?

Comment: no i don't, i need to get it working looking for help to implement the redirect, thanks.

Comment: If You do not have any login form box present at all pages (like in header or a side column) then there is only the default link leading to a page `index.php?route=account/login` and then I do not understand to what page do You want to redirect after the user is logged in...Maybe You want to achieve this scenario: 1. User clicks on **Log In** link. 2. User fills the login form and clicks on submit button. 3. After he is logged in You want him to redirect to the page from which he clicked on **Log In** link. <- is that what You want to achieve...?

Comment: yes thats it! cheers.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this scenario:

1. User clicks on Log In link.
2. User fills the login form and clicks on submit button.
3. After he is logged in You want him to redirect to the page from which he clicked on Log In link.

You would have to edit `catalog/controller/account/login.php` **controller**. Add this right after the `public function index() {` line:

```
if(!isset($this->session->data['login_redirect'])
        && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], HTTP_SERVER) !== false
                || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], HTTPS_SERVER) !== false)) {
    $this->session->data['login_redirect'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Please be wise of [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer) may not contain any URL depending on the HTTP server and/or browser used thus this may not work all the time (and there is no other chance to retrieve the URL user came from).

Now in that same file find the line:

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
```

(should be line 59, my version is 1.5.5.1) and change it to:

```
if(!empty($this->session->data['login_redirect'])) {
    $url = $this->session->data['login_redirect'];
    unset($this->session->data['login_redirect']);
    $this->redirect($url);
} else {
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

This should work in most cases.

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to be careful when using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` as it can be a security issue with CSRF so you should check that the domain is in fact your sites

Comment: @JayGilford Thanks for pointing out, some browsers gives ability to modify the `HTTP_REFERER` header as a feature, thus I added a check into the first condition.

Comment: no joy :( there were 3 instances of $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL')); in the login.php file though?

Comment: I meant only the first one...But if You replace all of them by the code above it will be OK anyway... Happy replacing ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to shadyyx's answer above. I had too little rep power to up-vote it, so instead I'm posting my vQmod code here as a thank you.

Note that the code below replaces all 3 instances of `$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'))` since replacing only the first instance did not work for me (it has not been exhaustively tested).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
<id>Login Redirects (to where user was prior to login)</id>
<version>1</version>
<vqmver>2.4.1</vqmver>
<author>Salad_Dressing (with help from shadyyx)</author>
<file name="catalog/controller/account/login.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            public function index() {
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            if(!isset($this->session->data['login_redirect']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], HTTP_SERVER) !== false || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], HTTPS_SERVER) !== false)) {
                $this->session->data['login_redirect'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            }
        ]]></add>
    </operation>

    <operation>
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
            $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            if(!empty($this->session->data['login_redirect'])) {
                $url = $this->session->data['login_redirect'];
                unset($this->session->data['login_redirect']);
                $this->redirect($url);
            } else {
                $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
            }
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
</modification>
```