# Will HTTP_REFERER be correct when using header('Location..')?

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm creating a Single Sign-on service for a company website with different webapplications on different subdomains. Let's call the subdomain with the SSO service 'Server' (sso.domain.com) and the subdomain with the SSO consumer 'Client' (client.domain.com).

To login on the Client, a form on the client is submitted to a page on the client. On this page, a Header('Location: sso.domain.com/login.php'); is used with some data attached.

Will the HTTP_REFERER that can be read on the Server always be consistent and correct? In this way, I can check whether the origin of the login request and the callback to redirect to are the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how reliable is HTTP\_REFERER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer)

Answer (score 0):

> Will the HTTP_REFERER that can be read on the Server always be consistent and correct?

No. Pass the parameters in the redirect URL.

Comment: That's what I'm doing anyway. But I want to check the callback URL against the origin of the request. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: By adding `&origin=$origin` to the redirect URL. Although that can be forged as easily as the referrer.