# $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] issue

Tags: php, html, http-referer

I've just trying to set 'if' rules for my website, and I'm facing with little problem
I want to allow:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] = "http://t.co/XXXXXX")
{ allowed }
```

XXXXXX - unique end of each link, so I need to set that every visit, which begins with t.co would be accepted. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [PHP string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Comment: *"Using `HTTP_REFERER` isn't reliable, it's value is dependent on the HTTP Referer header sent by the browser or client application to the server and therefore can't be trusted."* - [**Read more...**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/)

Comment: If your plan is to use referrer to implement something important such as security or some such, then you need to change your plan.  HTTP_REFERRER is completely untrustworthy and can be spoofed with virtually no effort.

Comment: [`int stripos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] );`](http://php.net/stripos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following snippet:

```
if (preg_match('/^https?:\/\/t\.co\//', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    # allowed
}
```

This will also match https requests, by the way.

Alternatively, you can use parse_url, like this:

```
$parsed = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if ($parsed['host'] === 't.co') {
    # allowed
}
```

Keep in mind though that $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] might not be set or empty, thus an additional

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
```

is useful in both cases.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'` missing square bracket.

Comment: parse_url is the best answer here I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the first 12 characters:

```
if (substr($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],0,12) == "http://t.co/" || substr($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],0,13) == "https://t.co/")
{ allowed }
```

Comment: thanks, I'll accept answer in 10 min. :)

Comment: Shouldn't those be `==` instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], '://t.co/') === 4
 || stripos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], '://t.co/') === 5) {
    // Allowed
```