# Add multiple referrer links

Tags: php

I protect page from being access and can only access it by a referrer page, here is my code on landing page

```
<?php 
// request file coming from test referrer
    if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"http://aqsv.com/sites2/testreffer/tp1.php"))
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test Landing Page 1</h1>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
// redirect to redirect.php
else  {
header("Location: http://aqsv.com/sites2/testlander/redirect.php");
}
?>
```

and this is the referrer page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Test Refererrer 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test Refererrer 2</h1>
<a href="http://aqsv.com/sites2/testlander/lp1.php">Link me to landing page1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

this work perfectly on single referrer page only, what i want to do is to have multiple referrer page to access the page , Im new to php and really dont have any idea to do this.. I tried adding http referrer using if else like this

```
<?php 
// request file coming from test referrer
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"http://aqsv.com/sites2/testreffer/tp1.php"));
elseif(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"http://aqsv.com/sites2/testreffer/tp2.php"))
        {
?>
```

but the second link is not working. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have a semi-colon in `testreffer/tp1.php"));` <= *the buck stops here*.

Comment: It should be noted if you're going to use this in a public facing website that browsers can be explicitly told never to send referrer headers for privacy reasons.

Comment: Sidenote: [**Using `HTTP_REFERER` isn't reliable**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/) - *"Don't rely on it for any serious purpose."*

Comment: Thanks for answering Fred, Im really new to php and this is the only way i think is the best to avoid accessing the landing page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take an array containing all your valid referrer domain. E.g.

```
<?php
$valid_domains = array(
    'domain1',
    'domain2',
    'domain3'
);

// The checking for valid domain
if ( in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $valid_domains) )
{
?>
Your HTML goes here....
<?php
}
?>
```

Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Hope the idea will help you.

Comment: Thank u so much for answering that fast @Barmar. Works perfect now! I really learned a lot on php by asking questions here :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax if `if/elseif...` is:

```
if (something) {
    body
} elseif (somethingelse) {
    body
}
```

But you have no `body` for your `if`, only for the `elseif`, so nothing happens in that case.

Since you want the same body for all your tests, you should just use a single `if` with multiple conditions connected by `OR`:

```
if (stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"http://aqsv.com/sites2/testreffer/tp1.php") ||
    stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"http://aqsv.com/sites2/testreffer/tp2.php")) {
    ...
}
```

Another way you can do this is by putting all the allowed referers in an array, and then doing:

```
if (in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), $allowed_referers)) {
    ...
}
```

I use `strtolower()` to make it case-insensitive, like your original tests.