# $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; is null on firefox when accessed vai `swf` movie

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, firefox

I'm trying to upload file using `flash` So

I've following code in `action-script`:

```
var fileRef:FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
fileRef = new FileReferenceList();
fileRef.browse(new Array( new FileFilter( "Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png" )));
fileRef.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectHandler);

var uploadURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var uploadPhotoScript:String = "http://localhost/uploader/upload.php";
uploadURL.url = uploadPhotoScript;

function fileSelectHandler(event:Event):void {
    for each(var fileToUpload:FileReference in fileRef.fileList){
            uploadSingleFile(fileToUpload);
        }
}

function uploadSingleFile(file:FileReference):void {
file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onUploadProgress);
file.upload(uploadURL);
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
}

function onUploadProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var f:FileReference = e.currentTarget as FileReference;
    var fileName:String = f.name; //Now I know which file it is, I can update accordingly
    var progress:Number = (e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal) * 100; //shows percent, you might want to round this off using Math.round(number);
}

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("upload complete");
}
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]){
  $ref=$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
  $ref=explode($ref,"/");
  $ref=$ref[2];
   if($ref=="localhost"){
     if(!empty($_FILES)){
        $tmpfile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
        $targetfile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($tmpfile, $targetfile);
     }
  }
else{
header("location:NotLocalhost.html");
exit;
}
}
else{
header("Location:NOREF.html");
exit;
}
?>
```

This code works fine in all browsers except firefox. coz In firefox `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFRER"]` becomes null and `NOREF.html` is displayed.

Also in firefox when the script is accessed by another `html` or `php` script then works fine, but when is accessed vai `swf` movie which is in turn `<embeded>` in `html` page. Then the `REFERER` becomes null.

Any ideas? How can I solve this?

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the HTTP referrer too much. Some browser don't send it, and it can be spoofed.

Comment: Sidenote link > http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ (how reliable is HTTP_REFERER)

Comment: most `$_SERVER["HTTP_x"]` variables can be _controlled by user_.