# PHP increment by 1 issue

Tags: php

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];                       //get IP
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];                 //get referer
$time = time();                                      //extracting timestamp
$date = date('d-m-y H:i:s',$time);                   //generating date
$f = fopen("log.php", "a");                          //opening files
$counter = fgetc("hitleap.txt");
$f2 = fopen("hitleap.txt", "w+");

if($referer == "http://hitleap.com/traffic-exchange"){
fwrite($f2, $counter++);                             
fclose($f2);
} else { 
fwrite ($f, '<div class="spoiler"><input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this)" value="Show/Hide" />
Data/Ora: <b>['.$date.']</b><br>
<div class="inner" style="display:none">
IP: <b>['.$ip.']</b> <br>
Provenienza: <b>['.$referer.']</b>
</div></div><br>



 ');
fclose($f);
}
```

Basically if the site visitor is coming from hitleap site, I want to increment a number inside a txt file by 1. If not, add into another log file his IP and referer inside a spoiler.
The second part works pretty well but I can't still get the first part to work

Also the hitleap.txt somehow gets flushed everytime the "else" applies.

**EDIT**
Solved like this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$time = time();
$date = date('d-m-y H:i:s',$time);
$hits = file_get_contents("hitleap.txt");
$nhits = $hits+1;

if($referer == "http://XXX"){
$f2 = fopen("hitleap.txt", "w+");
fwrite($f2, $nhits);
fclose($f2);
} else {
$f = fopen("log.php", "a");
fwrite ($f, 'wh@tever u want here');
fclose($f);
}
```

seems to work fine for me

Comment: `fwrite($f2, $counter++);` at first it writes the value and than it increments the `$counter`. write it as `fwrite($f2, ++$counter);`

Comment: $f2 = fopen("hitleap.txt", "w+"); - This will open file hitleap.txt in write mode, after deleting its previous contents. It should work fine if you put this line inside the if block

Comment: Sidenote about `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` => http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Answer (score 2):

You'll wanna use

```
fwrite($f2, ++$counter);
```

instead of

```
fwrite($f2, $counter++);
```

What's happening is that your incrementing the variable after it's been written to file and not before.  The solution will increment the variable before writing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your final code would be:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];                       //get IP
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];                 //get referer
$time = time();                                      //extracting timestamp
$date = date('d-m-y H:i:s',$time);                   //generating date
$f = fopen("log.php", "a");                          //opening files
$counter = fgetc("hitleap.txt");

// this line has been moved into the if block

if($referer == "http://hitleap.com/traffic-exchange"){
$f2 = fopen("hitleap.txt", "w+"); // here it is
fwrite($f2, ++$counter);                       // using ++$counter      
fclose($f2);
} else { 
fwrite ($f, '<div class="spoiler"><input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this)" value="Show/Hide" />
Data/Ora: <b>['.$date.']</b><br>
<div class="inner" style="display:none">
IP: <b>['.$ip.']</b> <br>
Provenienza: <b>['.$referer.']</b>
</div></div><br>



 ');
fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Tried this one out. The hitleap.txt file still gets flushed instead of its number incremented.