# How can I only allow acces to a .php file from a .js file and restrict the rest?

Tags: javascript, php, json, apache, .htaccess

In order to protect some JSON files, I am trying to limit the access to one unique JavaScript file which loads some array with those JSON files.

I have been checking out some .htaccess examples around, using codes like the one below.

I have a folder called `data` with the JSON file: `localhost/myWebsiteFolder/data/fileToProtect.json`

So I created a .htaccess file in that folder whose address is `localhost/myWebsiteFolder/data/.htaccess`

And its content is:

```htaccess
   <FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|json|php)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Allow from "localhost/myWebsiteFolder/*.*"
</FilesMatch>
```

The file becomes restricted but I can’t access it from another file…

I’ve trying with another example and I get similar results.

Comment: This can't be done... HTTP is stateless and doesn't care where it is being called from. You could check the refer header but than can be spoofed.

Comment: I am curious on what `allow access from a .js file` means here.

Comment: Related questions: [htaccess - Deny access to folder but allow access to file via php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742510/htaccess-deny-access-to-folder-but-allow-access-to-file-via-index-php?rq=1) and [deny direct access to a folder and file by htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282124/deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-and-file-by-htaccess?rq=1)