# Make webpage not embeddable

Tags: php, iframe, embed

I'm developing a PHP website and it's crucial that some of its webpages, which are user generated, must be not embeddable in an iframe on other domains unless I want to.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I noticed i.e. that Vimeo offers premium users to set a list of domains on which a video can be embedded, so I imagine that this is possible in some ways, despite I haven't found anything around...

Thanks!

Comment: use mask in ur url, control access by using login credential system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include a javascript-code on pages that are not allowed as/in iframes, that redirects the top-frame and the iframe becomes useless in most cases.

```
if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
    window.top.location.href = window.location.href;
}
```

Most modern Browsers also respect the header-field `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` that can be set to `DENY` (page did not get displayed inside frames) or `SAMEORIGIN` (same as DENY, but only if the domain is not the same).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [referrer](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $allowedReferers)) {
    // STOP !!!!
    echo "not today baby!";
    die();
}

// GO !!!!
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not always reliable => http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Comment: @Fred-ii- yep, totally agree. Best to use a combination of PHP to look at `HTTP_REFERER` and JS to inspect things at the start of rendering.

Comment: Whoever came up with that directive, should've came up with a Plan-B lol