# PHP redirect domain to the correct domain

Tags: php, redirect

I have two websites (domain1.com and domain2.com) with link button to basedomain.com website. 
In the basedomain.com I have one button to link back to the domain1.com

How I can redirect the users back to the website from which they came (domain1.com or domain2.com)

in basedomain.com I have a simple a href link:

```
<a href="http://domain1.com/" >Go back to Homepage</a>
```

Comment: You need to capture `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` when the request comes in for `basedomain.com`. It will have the url of the previous page. Realize that people may come to `basedomain.com` without ever going through your other two domains. So this is not fool-proof. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: You should add that information to the button or the form that the button is on so you can store / use it on your `basedomain.com` page. What do the buttons look like, are they part of a form?

Comment: Note to people about `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ it isn't fully reliable.

Comment: you can use cookies and/or sessions for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the link of the 'from' domain to your basedomain link like this:

```
<a href="http://basedomain.com?from=domain1.com">
```

Optional you can add some security to your link to verify that the 'from' part isn't altered, using HMAC. Or match the 'from' value at you base domain against a whitelist that contain the possible 'from' URL's.

Hope this helps?

**EDIT**

Easiest way for now is to go with the whitelist variant. To do that, you have to do the following steps:

1. Create a link to the basedomain from each (sub)domain like i've done above.
2. The 'from' var contains the identifier of the current domain, for example the name (domain1.com)
3. Build an array on your basedomain containing the valid enrties like this:

   ```
   $validDomains = [
       'domain1.com' => 'http://www.domain1.com/',
       'domain2.com' => 'http://www.domain2.com/',
       ....
   ];
   ```
4. Building the back link on your base domain, start with checking the 'form' key against the validDomains. If the key exists, add the value of the validDomains as href link:

   ```
   $linkForYourHref = null;
   if (!empty($_GET['form']) && isset($validDomains[$_GET['form']))  {
       $linkForYourHref = $validDomains[$_GET['form'];
   }


   //button code
   if (!is_null($linkForYourHref))   {
        //link to $linkForYourHref
   }
   ```

An another options is to authenticate your 'from' part of the basedomain link by adding a hash to the URL like this:

```
<a href="http://basedomain.com?from=domain1.com&key=theHMACkey">
```

See [Paragonie](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly) for more info about that

Comment: thank you for your answer sanderbee but can you make your example exactly how I need? Because i am not so good developer and I don;t understand very well. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> [HTTP_REFERER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) - which holds the previous url from which the user came from

- store the url in a variable and output it inside href

  ```
   <?php 
      if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=""){
            $link = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
      } else {
           $link = "http://www.default_link.com";
      }

      echo '<a href="'.$link.'" > Go back </a>';

  ?>
  ```

Comment: thank you this is perfect, but in case that there is not any HTTP_Refferer how I can setup the default domain?

Comment: see edits to my post. set a condition if http_referer is blank

Comment: You can never rely on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] being set so it is
generally unsafe to rely on it. There are browser preferences and other
3rd party apps that can prevent it being passed or otherwise altered.

Comment: yes sanderbee has right, if I will add a link for example in some ads, the customers will be redirect back to that ads site, right?

Comment: That also, and some browsers doesn't support it anymore, so your default-link is called. An another option is to work with whitelists and/or keys (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
header("Location: http://basedomain.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

to get the domain.

And use

```
 header('Location: '.$refer);
```

to redirect.