# HTTP_REFERER sends me to the same page

Tags: php, http-referer

I'm using php and I'm trying to add a functionality to my contact form that sends me the page that precedes the contact page.
I added this line of code on my form code:

```
$httpReferer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;
$e_body = "Provenance : $httpReferer ";
```

This works fine and shows me a link, but the problem is that the link is the same contact page (http://...contact.php).
What I need is the page that the user visited just before getting to that contact.php page.

Anyone knows why is this happening?
Is there a way to go back 2 pages instead of one?

Thanks :)

Comment: you're missing a `?` for your ternary operator. Plus, don't rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not 100% reliable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Comment: Ah the "?" is a typo and I'll correct it here ! It is correct in my actual code ^^
I've tried using the variable $HTTP_REFERER without passing by $_SERVER but it didn't work neither :/

Comment: I always take posted code literally ;-) you'd be amazed as to what people actually use, and it's what they post. Call it "experience" ;-)

Comment: the only way I know to go back 2 pages is with `javascript:window.history.go(-2)` you could implement that in PHP with an echo. Another way would be to use a breadcrumb method, but that would require some fancy work. I've seen it done before, but I'd probably have to spend up to 1/2 hour trying to find it. If you want to use a real back button, use sessions and/or cookies. Again, don't rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Consult http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ for the "why".

Comment: I posted an example for you in an answer below.

Comment: I'm sorry for this delay guys ! I've been traveling since the last time I posted my question and I couldn't have an access since then.
Thank you Fred for your answer which was with a great help to me :)

Comment: You're very much welcome Ayoub, glad to have been of help and hope your travels went well, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to have a back button, is to add a hidden input to your form (seeing that is what you are using in a contact page), and using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as a value and assigning a session array to it and using sessions. Cookies could also be used, but I've used sessions in my example.

First start the session:

```
<?php 
session_start();

// you can uncomment it to destroy previously set sessions
// session_destroy();

$_SESSION['back'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

?>

<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="goback" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>">
...
</form>
```

Then on the second page: `page2.php`

```
<?php 
session_start();

// Your POST information for your contact code goes here

echo "<a href=\"$_SESSION[back]\">Go back</a>";

?>
```

Or, to have the full `http` call:

```
$link = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SESSION['back'];

echo "<a href=\"$link\">Go back</a>";
```

Sidenote: As I stated in comments,

The only way I know to go back 2 pages is with `javascript:window.history.go(-2)` which you could implement that in PHP with an echo.

Another way would be to use a breadcrumb method, but that would require some fancy work.

- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` isn't fully reliable.
- Read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ as to why.

You could also use a header to redirect, but make sure you're not outputting before header.

Ref:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

---

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

---

Footnotes:

> *What I need is the page that the user visited just before getting to that contact.php page.*

If there wasn't a referer to the page, then there is no way for a user to go back, because there is nothing to go back to, unless they use their browser's back arrow button.

- A referer is a link that a person would have clicked from, either from your site or another.

If there was no referer, you can use `javascript:window.history.go(-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (see other comments), then store this in a session when the contact form is loaded so you can use this when the form is submitted.

```
// Store the referring URL when loading the contact form.
$_SESSION['ref'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

// Redirect user back to referring URL when submitting the form.
header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['ref']);
unset($_SESSION['ref']);
die;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
die;
```

Hope it will help you