# Header location php

Tags: php, if-statement, header

I've made this block of code:

```
$tag = $_GET['tag'];

if ($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://sitename.com/portfolio' || $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'sitename.com/tags/?tagname=' . $tag ) : ?>

<figure class="folio-item">
    <img src="<?php echo $mod->src; ?>" alt="">
</figure>

<?php  else : ?>
   <?php header('http://sitename.com/portfolio'); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

So if the statement is true it has to make the figure, which does work. 
but when the statement isn't true it gives me a empty file instead of heading me to sitename.com/portfolio

how can i make this work?

the Solution:

```
$tag = $_GET['tag'];

if ($_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://sitename.com/portfolio' ||       $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'sitename.com/tags/?tagname=' . $tag ) : ?>

<figure class="folio-item">
    <img src="<?php echo $mod->src; ?>" alt="">
</figure>

<?php  else : ?>
   <?php header('Location:http://sitename.com/portfolio'); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

I added Location: to the header function like Brian said.

Comment: syntatically speaking `$tag = $_GET['tag']` is missing a semi-colon and `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER']` is missing a quote and isn't reliable to use neither.

Comment: ohhh, I did found the problem, the semi-colon exists in my file, didn't type it here.  <?php header('http://sitename.com/portfolio'); ?> must be <?php header('location: http://sitename.com/portfolio'); ?>

Comment: then look up on how to use header http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Is the code you just added your code or the code in the question? Please update.

Comment: do not exactly know what you mean, the code I added in the comments is the solution to my problem

Comment: In regards to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ as to why it isn't reliable. There are other/better ways to do that. Oh and this `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER']` will fail  as I said. the missing quote. So, for what you posted, I can't see how that will ever work. Update  your question for the right syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php will say differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to tell it that you are setting a location rather than another header attribute

```
<?php  else : ?>
   <?php header('Location: http://sitename.com/portfolio'); exit; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

the `exit;` statement tells it to stop executing which allows the redirect. You also need to make sure you don't spit out any html before you redirect.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that's it! Im going to use exit for sure, didn't thin about spitting html before the redirect cause that isn't going to work

Comment: It'll work without the exit, but if a browser is misbehaving, more PHP output could be observed, so it's always a good idea to put an exit after redirection.

Comment: glad i could help. And Dave is right, you don't really need it, but I've had issues come from it and the `exit;` helped a lot.