# how to get website address directed to my site

Tags: javascript, php

I need the site address that is redirecting the user to my website when my link in the other website is clicked.

How to get the website address that redirects to my site?

Comment: you ask the other website to create a banner link to your site

Comment: no i get url other website

Comment: ahh, @Aviram seems to have deciphered your question correctly

Comment: I think the answer $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] sorry for bad grammer

Comment: as I said, @Aviram seems to know what you were asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`.

Comment: It isn't reliable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ and will most certainly not work with Facebook for one thing, should the OP want to use it for that. 9 times out of 10, that's what they need it for.