# delete value from database using link

Tags: php, sql

I have a page that shows comments, "comments.php", and I include the page on any other page that I want comments to show. I am trying to implement a way to delete comments if needed. Each comment has an auto-increment "commentID". Right now I'm using an action, and then just using a link to call the action.

When I hover over the link, the URL looks correct, but when I click it, the page refreshes and nothing happens. Any ideas?

Action:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'delete') {
    $sql = "delete from " . $db_prefix . "comments where commentID = " . (int)$_GET['id'];
    mysql_query($sql) or die('error deleting user: ' . $sql);
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Show comments and show link to delete: (unnecessary code has been left out)

```
echo '<a href="/comments.php?action=delete&id=' . $result['commentID'] . '">delete</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you typecasting in the query?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: you're using the wrong method as @Script47 said. `?xxx` is a GET method, not POST.

Comment: Also maybe I'm missing something but you check for `$_POST['action']` yet use `$_GET` in the query.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is unreliable http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/ so don't "rely" on that.

Comment: @Script47 The typecasting is so the value must be an int, a way to avoid injection. https://eval.in/416528

Comment: You should require some sort of authentication on the delete page. As is a malicious user could right a simple < 4 line script and delete a majority of your records, if not all of them.

Comment: @chris85 he could use `intval();` but my issue was, why was he doing it ***in*** the query. Why not assign a variable outside of the query, it would make his code cleaner.

Comment: Regarding your 404 below; you do realize that `/comments.php` goes to the root of your public folder. Make sure it exists in there and that it's not named "Comments.php" with an uppercase "P". On Linux, those are two different filenames. Check that that file doesn't have an include/require which contains a file that either doesn't exist, or is somewhere else on the server. Also check your form's action if there is one.

Comment: If you're using the same file for everything, just omit the file name `?action=delete&id`

Comment: `or die('error deleting user: ' . $sql);` doesn't help you, `or die(mysql_error())` does. Edit: I have to hit the hay, good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I took out `/comments.php` and it started working. Along with Script47's answer. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you're mixing `$_POST` with `$_GET`.

Try this,

```
 ?php
 if ($_GET['action'] == 'delete') {
    if (!ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) {
        exit("ID has to be an int.");
    }
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);

    $sql = "DELETE FROM `" . $db_prefix . "comments` WHERE `commentID` = " . $id;

    mysql_query($sql) or die('error deleting user: ' . $sql);

    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
?>
```

Your link also shows `action=delete` so you should be checking if `$_GET` action equals delete.

**Edit 1**

Your code is prone to [`SQL injection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you are still using `MySQL` even though it has been deprecated, you should use either `MySQLi` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Not to mention your `$_GET` data is being passed on to the query without being sanitized, you should start using `intval` it would make it better and prevent `XSS`. Please read up on the function `intval` and `ctype_digit` to get a better understanding at what it does.

**Edit 2**

***Scrap `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`***

[How reliable is HTTP_REFERER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer/6023980#6023980)

**Edit 3**

As noted in comments:

*"If you're using the same file for everything, just omit the file name `?action=delete&id`"*

which would explain the 404 you mentioned in comments.

Comment: Aware of sql injection, thanks. So now I'm just getting a 404 error when I click the delete link...

Comment: @MarkJones If you are aware, then please fix the issues. Also read **Edit 2**.

Comment: Took out `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, probably didn't need it anyway. Still getting 404. Is there something wrong in my link?

Comment: @MarkJones read the latest comment in the OP's chain of comment.

Comment: Thanks @Script47! Works like a charm after I took out the `/comments.php`.

Comment: Thank @Fred-ii- for that. But glad I could help for the rest of it.

Comment: @Script47 You're welcome. Glad this one got resolved.