# How to obtain two previous page's URL in php

Tags: php, session, url

I have a page named `Login.php`. I need the URL of the page before the last page.

When the user login form will submit to `check_login.php` which checks their username and password. Then I will redirect the user to `index.php`.

The issue is I want the user to be redirected to the second to last page they visited.

***EXAMPLE:***

**First URL:** `www.example.com/posts/1`

**Second URL:** `www.example.com/login.php`

**Third URL:** `wwww.example.com/check_login.php`

So, if username and password are correct => `header('location: www.example.com/posts/1');`

There is a solution to get the previous URL:

```
// login.php
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

// check_login.php
header('location: '.$_SESSION['url']);
```

But I need to get the second to last URL, not the last URL.  How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: As far as I know, no

Comment: no. referer only has (sometimes/maybe) the IMMEDIATELY preceding page. if you want to track multiple previous pages, you'll have to record that somehow.

Comment: Sidenote: You shouldn't rely on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: @Fred-ii- why ? `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` does not work correctly ?

Comment: Have a read http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do what other people have done:

**First solution:**

Create a `hidden` field in your pages so that when a user clicks on `login` it will take him to the `login.php` page with the previous link. Then you can do anything you want (like, saving it to `$_SESSION['url']`) with this link.

**Second Solution:**

Imagine you have an anchor like this:
`<a href="login.php">login</a>`.
Instead of using just `login.php` you can use `login.php?redirect_to=http://example.com/post/1` so that you can access the url from your `login.php` page with a `$_GET['redirect_to']` request.

**NOTE:** Always remember to sanitize user input data.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose @GinoDeMaria's answer works, but it is doing some unnecessary checks and still making multiple calls to assign variables.

**USING SESSIONS**

So a more simple way to do it would be:

```
$_SESSION['2last_url'] = isset($_SESSION['last_url']) ? $_SESSION['last_url'] : null;
$_SESSION['last_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

So `$_SESSION['2last_url']` contains the value you are looking for.

Now as Gino said the user agent does not always set `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` properly.

**USING REDIRECT VALUES IN REQUEST**

This method is a bit more elegant, and could prove to be much more useful.  Simply tell the `check_login.php` where to redirect the user after login.

First we tell the login page where to redirect.  So instead of going to `login.php`, we go to `login.php?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpost%2F1`.  (You may notice the redirect URL looks odd, this is due to URL encoding.  Either [use a tool like this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) or [check out PHP's urlencode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)).

Now in your `login.php` you must add a hidden field which contains this value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $_GET['redirect']; ?>">
```

Then in `check_login.php` just get that value:

```
header("Location: " . $_POST['redirect']);
```

And there you go.

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to know there is a way to I can obtain two previous url directly ?

Yes, you have need of the session.
e.g

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['url']))
   $lurl = array();
else
   $lurl = $_SESSION['url']);
$count = count($lurl);
$lurl[$count % 2] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$_SESSION['url'] = $lurl;
```

Caveat: (php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php))
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: your answer is like what I said, anyway thanks, +1 up vote for you.