# php not working when user click in BACK bottom in browser

Tags: php

I have a problem and I don't know if anyone has a solution...
I have an online.php script that gets user ip and data and write it on mysql:

```
$browser     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include_once ("$root/config.php");

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

...
$sb4154 = $on124->num_rows;

if ($sb4154 == 0) {
 $url=@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 $ihghg = $mysqli_link->prepare("INSERT INTO online (ip, hora, browser) VALUES (?,now(),?)");
 $ihghg->bind_param('ss', $ip, $browser);
 $ihghg->execute();
 $ihghg->close();
}
else {
 $ihghg = $mysqli_link->prepare("UPDATE online SET `hora` = now() WHERE `ip` = ? LIMIT 1");
 $ihghg->bind_param('s', $ip);
 $ihghg->execute();
 $ihghg->close();
}
```

it is basically that. (I use ... to sum up).

My php, when you click in a link it opens the image:

```
<a href="image.jpg">
```

So the user needs to click back in the browser to see more pictures. The problem is here, when user click back, this include online.php script not work, the UPDATE time not set the hour.

Why it is not working when user click back in browser?

Comment: PHP doesn't run again when user clicks back button. Browser just retrieves the cached version of the page.

Comment: ...therefore, use a header.

Comment: no way to force php to run again?

Comment: Maybe... sure, if you ensure that the window.location gets reloaded, you might be able to get away with that, as a refresh and it can be done, and there are a few ways to do this. Other than that, use a header.

Comment: However, you shouldn't rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and here's why http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Comment: oh, thank you for the http_referer!