# How to send all referral traffic without .htaccess?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, bots

I have a website with two landing pages (www.abc.com):

- landing page- 1 =(www.abc.com/index.php)
- landing page- 2 =(www.abc.com/index1.php)

Conditions of landing page 2:

- robots can not be allowed
- referral traffic allowed for united states only (if anyone connects from another country the website will open the default page).

Note: Referral traffic means the traffic which we purchased from adnetworks.

How can we stop robots and how we can redirect the referral traffic from a selected country and how will we detect the country?

Comment: use php redirect - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431

Comment: Hire a web developer.

Comment: you seem to have forgotten to show any code. It should go right where you put `'enter code here'`

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP script, you can always check the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] value and redirect to the appropriate page using:

```
header('Location: '.$pageYouWanToRedirectTo);
exit();
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` isn't reliable and here's why http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/