# Get url of page on which the error page was clicked in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, exception

I am not sure if this is possible but I have a requirement so had to ask!

I am handling errors/exceptions in `Application_Error` event in `Global.asax`.

This is working fine and I am able to get the url in which the error occurred.

I would like to get the page on which this url resided clicking of which in turn gave me this error. You can say 1 level up.

So, for example I have a page say `www.example.com/home-loans.aspx` on which there is a link which opens `www.example.com/problem-url.aspx`. Which I click this link `www.example.com/problem-url.aspx` throws an error and I am able to correctly catch this along with the url `www.example.com/problem-url.aspx` but I am not able to figure how to capture `www.example.com/home-loans.aspx`.

If the link is clicked from outside the website (say from a google search) then this value can come as `null` or whatever is possible.

Please let me know if you need the code for `Application_Error` event in `Global.asax`.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using the [`UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

This will give you the URL in the [`Refered`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) header.

However, the header [may or may not always be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer).

Comment: Seems to be working. Have handled null for this property if it is not available. Will try out a few days and update you. Upvote from me.

Comment: Yes it did! Accepting answer! Thanks a million! Will comment if I need any clarifications! Should be fine right?