# prevent users from accessing the login.php process file within browser nav bar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])==null){


    header("Location: login.html");
}
?>
<script>
$(function(){
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
{       
//This will capture all the inputs from the form
var infom = $("#myform").serialize();
        //$("#showresult").addClass('loader');                
        $.ajax({            
            beforeSend: function() { },         
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data:infom,          
            success: function(result){      
            //$("#showresult").removeClass('loader');
            $('#showresult').html(result);
            }
        });     
        e.preventDefault(); 
}
}); 
});
</script>
```

in the login.php file i placed that but it does nothing the user is still able to put in login.php within the browser navigation and still get to it. I want to stop them from doing so. I want that file to only call when i try to login on the login html page. Above is the ajax code used to display error message if any from php. when i combine it with the if post or http reffer, it redirects to a blank page with continuous loading.

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['id'])==null){` that by the way, is giving you a false positive. You need to split those up in two different conditionals. Hard to say also if you even started the session everywhere.

Comment: You can't stop it.

Comment: Yes i did start the session.

Comment: I'm assuming you're sending the form post data to login.php. Simply check if $_POST has not been set. if it hasn't redirect to login.html otherwise process if(!isset($_POST)){ redirect }

Comment: someone posted an answer now, ask them. I gave you an indication as to why your present code is failing you, being the first part of my comment. We also don't know what the rest of your pages look like and if you're using the same (wrong/invalid) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you can check with this

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="complete URL/login.html")
```

the url must be like http://www.example.com/login.html

and if you are submitting a form from login you must check $_POST .

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not dependable. Here, read for yourself http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/1415724

Comment: Getting this error" Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in" .   I did it like this if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="{http://localhost}/login.php"){

header("Location: login.html");
}

Comment: @ShannaChambers it doesnt need to be  { } i edited my answer !

Comment: if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!="http://localhost/login.php")
{ 
     header("Location: login.html");
}

Comment: *"tell me what i am doing wrong"* - @ShannaChambers [*I told you what you were doing wrong, from the beginning...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068596/prevent-users-from-accessing-the-login-php-process-file-within-browser-nav-bar#comment65485386_39068596). I take it you want me to post the actual syntax for it. PHP.net contains examples on how to use conditional statements.

Comment: @Masoud Haghbin Its working now but when i try to log in it takes me to a blank page and not the page i intended.

Answer (score 0):

login.php

```
// check if form has been submitted
IF (!isset($_POST)) { 
    Header('Location: login.html');
    die();

}
```

It would be wiser to use form tokens instead.

Comment: i wonder if its because i am using ajax to submit the form so i can get error message on the same page. It works but when i try to submit the form it gives me a blank page and wont redirect to the desired page.

Comment: Those are details we need to know. Please update your question.