# Query string is appending when using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php

Can someone explain me why when I execute this code multiple times it append the substring `?val=1` to my url?

Example: My script is located in index.php and if I execute it 3 times I will have this url in my browser: `http://localhost/index.php?val=1?val=1?val=1`

I would like to have `http://localhost/index.php?val=1` . . .

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['hidden']) && $_POST['hidden'] == 2){
            $page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            header("location: $page?val=1");
        }
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <input name ="hidden" value="2">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You shouldn't rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/1415724

Comment: The reason being, is that you're using the same file, so it redirects to the same one, uses the GET method and appends the `$page?val=1`. It's pretty much self-explanatory. Redirect it to another page instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a test before appending `?val=1`

```
if(isset($_POST['hidden']) && $_POST['hidden'] == 2){
    $page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if(strpos($page, '?val=1') === false) $page .= '?val=1';
    header("location: $page");
    exit; // Avoid further execution if more code is below this.
}
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not at all. Needs to be in there