# Emailing the url of 'page not found'

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I've created a php 404 page not found and added it to my server settings, this works great.

I want the page to email me the url of the missing page (e.g. `/folder/misspeltpagename.php)` but all I can get it the url of the 'page not found' page (e.g. `/error-docs/not-found.php`).

I'm using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to get the url.

Comment: you'd need to post your full code for this and if there's an `.htaccess` file into play

Comment: printing out $_SERVER, `print_r($_SERVER)` may give you more info, like REQUEST_URI

Comment: Do you want it to mail you something like domain.com/not-found.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

and then in 404.php use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Comment: Thank you @gio, this worked however I didn't look at my htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you simply redirect from any invalid page to your 404 page, so you can just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get what page directed to your 404 page.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` cannot be relied on. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/1415724