# Displaying hidden text using PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, statements

I am trying to come up with a php if statement for my site. I have a page called "research". There is text on this page with a link which says "contact me" This link links through to my contact page. Now, I need an if statement to say that if you are on the research page and you click on the contact me link, I need some text on the contact me page to be hidden and only be visible when you are on the contact page.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking, but I can tell you this: The things you have at your disposal are 1: the URL the person is currently on, the referrer (the URL they were last on when they clicked to get to "this" page), 3. Javascript or code to show/hide stuff at will.
Note: referrer isn't guaranteed to be available as some browsers block it for security purposes. Let me know if this gives you any ideas and I can code out how they'd work.

Comment: You mean `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: I think it is possibly a URL thing but I don't exactly know when to start. My site is www.counsellingrooms.co.uk and the research page is https://www.counsellingrooms.co.uk/research-p2

Comment: On the page text, it does say contact me which links to the contact page. On the contact page, there is some text on there which I don't want showing if you are coming from the research page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your contact page, you can get what you are looking for from:
`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.  It will tell you which page the user came from getting to the contact page.

However, you should not rely on this. Consult the following Q&A here on Stack Overflow:

- [How reliable is HTTP_REFERER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer)

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. That makes sense. Much appreciated