# Verifying an 'if' request from inside the website

Tags: php, security, laravel-5, token

I am trying to apply some protection for videos, played inside the website, from being downloaded by anything other than the player itself.

I figured out the following solution:

**In view file :**

```
@php
$token = uniqid ();
Session::put('videoToken',$token);
@endphp

<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="800" height="450"
                           poster="{{$post->thumbnails}}" data-setup="{}">
                        <source src="{{route('videoView',['id'=> $post->id]}}?token=$token" type='video/mp4'>

                        <p class="vjs-no-js">
                            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                        </p>
                    </video>
```

**videoView Route:-**

```
Route::get('/video/{id}',function(Request $request){
if ($request->token == Session::get('videoToken'))
{
$post = Post::find($id);
return response()->download($post->path, 'vid.mp4');
}
else{
die();
}
})->name('videoView');
```

For the above coding , I will make sure that the video file is only generated if '$token' is verified. How can I add an extra layer to verify if a request is coming from the page where the player is, so that anybody who tries to download the video by using the URL : http://mywebsite.com/video/5?token=54syrerrerw3rre , will not be able to.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible because **In HTTP protocol, each request is independent from the others**. But I've an approach to check request is from source domain or not. Try like this, it will return `true` if it is from same domain else `false`.

```
function requestIsFromSameSourceDomain(){

   if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))) {

     if (strtolower(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST)) != strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
       return false;
     }else{
       return true;
   }
  }
}
```

As per comment of **Funk Forty Niner** : please have a look here [How reliable is HTTP_REFERER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer?answertab=active#tab-top) before using above method

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` isn't reliable and here's why  [How reliable is HTTP_REFERER?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/1415724) - you should edit your answer to inform them about it. Edit: I noticed the edit, great.

Comment: Thanks for the source link..@FunkFortyNiner