# How can save the return path without HTTP_REFERRER?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a function based view that I only use to update a session:

```
def admin_privileges(request):
   // toggle request.session['is_admin']

   return
```

Typically I use this to toggle a session variable between `True` and `False`.

E.g. in a template:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin_privileges' %}">Toggle admin privileges</a>
```

How can I pass a variable and amend `return` in `admin_privileges` to return the user to the original view it was requested from?

I don't want to use anything on the front end, and I can't use `HTTP_REFERRER` as it's not always set.

I thought of passing something via the URL from the referring view?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

You can use `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` in your view which will return previous page.

or (more safely, [check this link to learn why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer))

You can pass the link (request.path for current page) as a parameter to admin_privileges link so:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin_privileges' %}?back={{ request.path }}">Toggle admin privileges</a>
```

In the view, you can get that parameter using request.GET and redirect using Django's redirect utilities.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately per the question I can't use HTTP_REFERRER. What's the correct syntax to use request.path in the `view`?

Comment: What do you mean exacly?