# How to get the URL called in the API?

Tags: php

I have deployed my REST API into different domain. So from frontend when API is called I need to get the browser URL.

Lets say, API is `https://api.xxx.xxx` and I am calling from `https://www.123.co`.

I have tried following lines, but it gives me only `https://api.xxx.xxx` while I need `https://www.123.co`

```
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you mean that you want to retrieve the Referral page? So not the page of the API but the page in your frontend that called the API? If so you need to use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];`

Comment: @SS Just so you know, HTTP referers aren't reliable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer