# PHP - open pdf if referral link is matching

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want my php website to open an pdf file only if the referral link is matching a certain condition.
I've got it to work to download the pdf if the conditions are met, but not to show the pdf in browser.
Somehow it reloads it or something resulting in an empty referral.

I use `.htaccess` to rewrite the pdf to a php page checking the referral.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).(pdf)$ check.php
```

Both `.htaccess` and `check.php` are in a subdirectory `sub1/sub2`. So the url of `check.php` is `mydomain.com/sub1/sub2/check.php`. The files I want to open are in another subdirectory `sub1/sub2/sub3`. So `mydomain.com/sub1/sub2/sub3/file.pdf`.

I use the following code in `check.php` to check the url for the file path and referral link.

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$paths = explode('/', $path);
$lastIndex = count($paths) - 1;
$fileName = $paths[$lastIndex];
$httpReferer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
foreach ($httpReferer as $key => $value) {
    if (str_starts_with($value, 'www.')) {
        $httpReferer[$key] = ltrim($value,"www.");
    }
}
$referrals = array("website1.com", "website2.com", "website3.com");
$fileDescription = 'funnyFileName';
```

Array `referrals` is the array with all approved referrals. To check if the referral is matching and if the file exists I use this code:

```
if (!empty(array_intersect($httpReferer, $referrals))) {
    $file = '../..'.$path;
    $file = strtok($file, "?");

    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        echo 'error1';
    } else {
        header("Content-type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileDescription.pdf");
        $filesize = filesize($file);
        header("Content-Length: $filesize");
        readfile($file);
    }
} else {
    echo 'error2';
}
```

If the referral is not matching it displays `error2` and if the file doesn't exist it displays `error1`.
If both are correct, the file is downloaded.
The pdf is called with a parameter for another non-related function in `check.php`, hence `$file = strtok($file, "?");`.

But I would like the pdf file to be displayed within the browser and not to be downloaded right away.
I know if I replace `attachment` to `inline` this should work, but it doesn't. It results in `error2`. So when displaying the pdf inline it reloads (?) the page resulting in an empty referral and `error2` occurs.

I tried debugging with `echo count(array_intersect($httpReferer, $referrals));`. It returns 1 if I the referral is matching and 0 if it's not. But when it reaches the point where it tries to display the file inline it also returns 0...

Comment: Can you please eloborate as to what did you try or debug other than "I know if I replace attachment to inline this should work, but it doesn't"?

Comment: Whether a PDF is show in the browser, elsewhere, or downloaded, is often a browser setting. This setting overrules your header. Also, [HTTP_REFERER is notorious unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023941/how-reliable-is-http-referer).

Comment: @Adi I tried using `inline`, but it resulted in displaying `error2` and don't know what to do to make it display the pdf. `attachment` works to download the file, but I want it to be displayed within the browser.
When skipping the referral check and just do the existance check, it does work with `inline`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I don't think this is the problem, because when skipping the referral check and just do the existance check, it does work with `inline`. But it doesn't when I do the referral check.
I tried debugging (`echo count(array_intersect($httpReferer, $referrals));`) It returns 1 if I the referral is matching and 0 if it's not. But when it reaches the point where it tries to display the file inline it also returns 0...

Comment: This error is probably in code you haven't shown us. Anyway, don't use: `(!empty(array_intersect($httpReferer, $referrals)))`, but use: `(in_array($httpReferer, $referrals))`.

Comment: I would suggest to systematically debug, check by echoing `$httpReferer` and `$referrals`, then error handling  and also i would say would be to test without referrer check as well.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware do you mean by overriding `Content-Disposition` header by user's browser preferences?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It's, of course, up to the maker of the browser how they exactly implement this.

Comment: @Adi When trying to reach the pdf from website1.com echoing `$httpReferer` results `Array`, but echoing the contents it results in `https://`, `website1.com` and `/`. Echoing the contents of `$referrals` results in `website1.com`, `website2.com` and `website3.com`. So this seems to work. Hence when I use the intersection it does actually work. But when changing `attachment` to `inline`  $httpReferer` results empty...

Comment: Here is how it is done in the Firefox settings: https://postimg.cc/PLS0Gtn3 I can also choose to download, and then it will always download, regardless of the headers. I looked in Chrome, but didn't find anything similar. Does anybody know if it in there somewhere.

Comment: I think you need to carefully redo your debugging, because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well i agree with @KIKOSoftware. Also otherwise you need alternative methods of access control such as user authentication or session-based authorization just to maintain referrer check i believe

Comment: The referer heaer is optional in HTTP, varies by browser and by version. Relying on this for mandatory functionality is not a good idea. That, and looking at the logic here makes me think this is the XY problem.

Comment: @KJ Thank you, but, I still couldn't find it in Chrome. Not with a manual search, or by searching the settings for: "additional contents". Then I googled: "chrome additional contents", and finally got [somewhere](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4410268). It's hidden in: "Settings" > "Privacy and security" > "Site settings" > "Additional content settings" > "PDF documents". I don't use Chrome that often....