# What are there circumstances in which no referer header will be passed for an https -> https link?

Tags: http, https, http-headers, http-referer

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17219924/568962), to a question concerning the `referer` header:

> Even when "linking" from HTTPS to HTTPS, most standard Web browsers will not inform this header when changing the domain name or network address destination.

I was not aware of this being the general case. Is this the general case? If not, what are the circumstances in which this is the case?

Please cite sources.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text quoted in the question was in fact an error, and has now been changed. So the answer to this question is:

Such circumstances would be outside the specification. No such circumstances are currently known.

Answer (score 0):

- Per spec referrer is removed in https=>http link : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2
- The referrer should be kept in others links, including https=>https (and I didn't see any browser removing referrer in https=>https link)
- A website can specifically ask to remove the referrer for outgoing links : https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/referrer-policy/