# Finding IP of a website that referring to my PHP script

Tags: php

I was creating a PHP file that generates a JavaScript code.

In case a website  reefers to my code:

```
<script src="http://myserver.com/myJS.php"></script>
```

My Question:
Is there a way in PHP to find out the **WEBSITE's IP** that's pointing to my script (Instead of the IP of the visitors of this website) ???

Thanks !

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: Hey LOKESH, My PHP runs on Linux CentOS

Comment: Can you check the HTTP referer?

Comment: Alright, so you want, that if someone adds your JS to his website, you should get a notification with the IP of the website owner.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless they add something(variable) to the link for you to catch this

Comment: How about [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is :

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

then do:

```
$parse   = parse_url($referer);
$host    = $parse['host'];
```

To get IP:

```
$ip      = gethostbyname($host);
```

The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted. [SOURCE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: same mix up,,, he need  REMOTE_ADDR,  not SERVER_ADDR

Comment: sorry my wrong. Read it wrong. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the `REFERER` http header, which should contain the URL of the site, but there is no guarantee that it will give you the correct value.

```
// First get the referrer
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

// Parse the referer url
$parts = parse_url($referer);

// Then do a NS lookup to get the IP
$ip = gethostbyname($parts['host']);
```

Just make sure that your are aware of the fact that the `REFERER` header can be faked. And the NS lookup is not always fast - or correct.

[Can I rely on Referer HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319862/can-i-rely-on-referer-http-header)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the OP is asking how to get the IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @putvande. I have fixed the example code now.

Comment: @TomerW Because they are two different things!!