# Prevent unsafe redirects

Tags: node.js, express

I know that:
Redirects that do not validate user input can enable attackers to launch phishing scams, steal user credentials, and perform other malicious actions.

like this :

```
res.redirect(req.query.url);
```

but is this redirection **UNSAFE** too ?

```
res.redirect(req.header('Referer') || '/');
```

**EDIT**

My website is multi-page so when I want to show error messages to user, I send flash message and redirect it to last page :

```
back(req , res) { 
  req.flash('formData' , req.body);
  return res.redirect(req.header('Referer') || '/'); 
}
```

So if **header ('Referer')** is unsafe, what's the **SAFE** way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I rely on Referer HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319862/can-i-rely-on-referer-http-header)

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr YES!

The referrer header is as unsafe as a query string. There’s no difference, because both comes from a user, thus can be manipulated. This said you have to validate the host part.