# Restrict acces to index.html and no other files in http server

Tags: http, lighttpd

I have a http server (e.g. http://www.web.com) running with `lighttpd`. The files composing this server are for instance:

```
index.html
files/img1.png
files/img2.png
```

If someone access http://www.web.com/files/img1.png, they can see that file. Is there a way I can block this type of access to my server?
I want does files to only be accessible if the user is redirected from `index.html` or used in it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to prevent hot-linking or deep-linking.  A **deterrent** is to require that requests set a Referer header, though some browsers or proxies strip the Referer header.

```
$HTTP["url"] != "/index.html" {
    $HTTP["referer"] != "https://www.my-site.net/index.html" {
        url.access-deny = ( "" )
    }
}
```

This is only a deterrent.  See also:
[Can I rely on Referer HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319862/can-i-rely-on-referer-http-header)