# Limit Google Functions to specific hostname in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase, and I'm not sure I'm going about what I'm trying to do the right way, but my question is essentially the title. For an app, I'd like to restrict my functions in Firebase to only be available on a custom hostname I've configured. I'm not sure if there is an easy enough way to do this without creating separate Firebase projects?

My main goal is to setup the functions to respond on a url like `api.myapp.com` while hooking into authentication that can have callback emails that are sent from `myapp.com`. I've done some digging and can't seem to find much on how to go about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are looking for [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check). Have you checked that out already?

Comment: If you want to prevent the Cloud Functions being called from other domains, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347293/only-allow-firebase-cloud-functions-through-hosting-rewrites

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation says](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-functions)

> The steps required to set up API Gateway to manage and secure a Cloud
> Functions backend service are outlined in the API Gateway Quickstarts.

[Documentation also says](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/api-access-overview)

> API Gateway uses Identity and Access Management (IAM) to control
> access to your API.

IAM is very granular and would allow you to specify domain names for *allow* action.